# Web Worker not returning result of performing operation

Tags: javascript, web-worker, lodash, turfjs

I have a web worker that is not returning the result of performing a computation,the method looks like this:

```
 self.checkIntersectionForLayerWith = function checkIntersectionForLayerWith(data) {

var checkIntersectionForLayer = function checkIntersectionForLayer() {

    var checkEachConflict = function checkEachConflict(feature){

        var conflict = turf.intersect(feature,data.rectFeature);

            if(conflict != null) {
                _.extend(conflict.properties,feature.properties);
                conflict.id = feature.id;
            }

            return conflict;
        };

    var intersectiontest = self._(data.features)
                                .map(checkEachConflict)
                                .pull(void 0)
                                .thru(self.turf.featurecollection)
                                .value();

    return {
            layerLabel:data.layerLabel,
            query:data.rectFeature,
            result:data.intersectiontest
        };


};

return checkIntersectionForLayer;
};
```

I invoke the method like this:

```
    self.startQuery = function startQuery(data) {

    if(data != null) {
        var checkIntersectionForLayer = self.checkIntersectionForLayerWith(data);
        var result = checkIntersectionForLayer();
        var payload = {
                type:'rectangle_query_worker_result',
                result:result
        };
        self.postMessage(payload);
    }
};

self.onmessage = function startQueryWorker(e) {
    if(e.data.type === 'start') {
        console.log("Inside the web worker,",e,e.data,e.data.payload);
        self.startQuery(e.data.payload);
    }
    else if(e.data.type === 'setup') { 
        self.setup();
    }
};
```

I call the nessecary libraries like this:

```
self.setup = function setup() {

    importScripts('/MapErpMobileDev/leaflet/mobile/js/lib/turf.js');
    importScripts('/MapErpMobileDev/leaflet/mobile/js/lib/lodash.compat.min.js');
};
```

Comment: What does this have to do with promises?

Comment: What exactly is "not returning"? Do you mean that `e.data.payload` is `null` and `postMessage` is never called?

Comment: @Bergi the result of calling `checkIntersectionForLayer` is returned as undefined.I am using the same code without a web worker and it works...e.data.payload was sometimes null but it got fixed,I still dont know how.`self._ ` and `self.turf` are defined and the chain is being executed as far as I know but I am getting no result after I return despite the fact that `intersectiontest` is not null.The result of `onmessage` in main thread resolves a `promise`

Comment: Wait, `intersectiontest` is not null (so you know it executed till there), but `checkIntersectionForLayer` does return `undefined` instead of that object with the `layerLabel`/`query`/`result` properties?

Comment: Should `data.intersectiontest` be `data[intersectiontest]`?

Comment: Or just `intersectiontest`?

Comment: Also, `.pull(void 0)` is equivalent to `.pull(undefined)` but `.map()` seems unlikely to return a sparse array. Nulls are more likely as indicated by the  code in `checkEachConflict()`. Try `.pull(null)` or, belt-and-braces, `.pull(null, void 0)`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the `turf.intersect` returns `undefined` if no intersection is found,i am using `!=null` because it does match `undefined` as well as `null`

Comment: Ah OK. I'd be happier working with nulls so try `var conflict = turf.intersect(feature, data.rectFeature) || null;` and `.pull(null)`. May make no difference but is cleaner.